# How can I scale a database/CPU intensive script?

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services, cloud

I currently have a PHP script that collects similar data from various sources, each data source is scraped and parsed every 120 seconds. At the moment I have 20 data sources, but I expect to integrate another 100 over the coming weeks.

Currently each data source is scraped in it's own thread, there is one main PHP script that will execute other scripts to perform the scraping work. This method allows all sources to be scraped at the same time, but it also puts a strain on the server, and a bottleneck on the database (MySQL).

I'm looking for a way to scale my current application, could I do something like this with AWS? Perhaps each of these scraping scripts could run in their own small server instance, each of these instances would be automatically created by a "main" instance and then die once the script has finished. I don't have any experience with AWS, so I'm not entirely sure if this is possible, or maybe it's just a bad idea.

The main question here is: How can I scale my current scraping script to allow for many new data sources? I'm interested in any solution even if I need to buy additional services.

Comment: If each data source has its own thread, then multiple instances (particularly one for each job) might be less efficient than running a larger single instance, if the processing goes on around the clock.  The pricing in AWS is significantly linear as you add cores/ECU and/or memory, within each instance family.  You don't want to stop an instance and start it too often, because you pay for the first hour every time you fire one up.

Comment: Drahcir - did you find a solution to your question?

Comment: @Jimbo I've not finished work on this yet, but your answer was very helpful and has put me on the right track.

Comment: @Drahcir I think it'd be cool if, once  your done and you have some spare time, you updated this post with how you went about it and marked yourself as correct. I don't mind losing the +15 to gain some extra insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You need a queueing system

You're describing a sort of worker / queue pattern, with your main server performing both the en-queueing and the worker execution, which of course is going to be a huge strain on your server.

First and foremost, your workers need to be asynchronous: you shouldn't be waiting for something that may or may not come back. You really should take a look at [ZeroMQ](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php%3aall) which, I might add, contains some of the best documentation on the planet. If you're willing to learn, take a look at how this works and follow some tutorials, there are plenty out there. Have your queue taking on new jobs and dispatching others elsewhere (i.e. to other boxes) hosted on your main server.

### Horizontal Scaling

You can create some sort of Instance Controller to handle AWS instances. You really just need to sit down and think about your logic (when do I want this many boxes, when do I want to shut them down). The API is pretty simple to use once you get your head around it. [Here's some code](https://gist.github.com/J7mbo/6796657) I wrote a while back to wrap Amazon's [SDK for PHP](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php). I'm not sure if it's working 100% with the latest version (I used it around a year ago), but the concepts are there - you have simple methods like `startBox()` or `stopBox()` that you call from your queue, and have your box automatically start doing it's stuff once it starts up.

You could use the `t1.micro` instances from Amazon [pricing here](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/), which has a **free tier** [info here](http://aws.amazon.com/free/faqs/) up to a certain limit.

Get it working properly, with a loop on your main server deciding how many boxes you need working at any one time given certain circumstances (no. of jobs in your database table, for example), and you'll have theoretically infinite scaling. Here's how I did it for my code:

- Tier 1: > 5 jobs, < 10 jobs = 1 box
- Tier 2: > 10 jobs, < 20 jobs = 2 boxes
- etc. etc.

### Advice

Log everything. Log every box coming up, every box coming down. Calculate your costs *in your code* and store them, maybe in a database, or log them, so you know exactly how much you're spending - your don't want things to get out of hand.

Make sure you open up your DB ports so your instances can talk to your DB to say when a job is done or anything else you need to pass between your "master" box and your "slave" boxes.

Also, if you're paying for web servers, you'll be billed *for the hour* with aws, so you need to get the time you start the box, and when it's time to shut down, only actually shut it down when 55 minutes or so has passed - you might as well get those extra minutes for what you're paying.

I can't really think of anything else. Do your research, figure out the best way to build a *queueing system*, and build it with scalability in mind (it can react and change to numbers that you control).

Comment: If you use Amazon SQS, you can tie autoscale triggers to SQS metrics.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer, very helpful. Will probably mark BA soon.

Answer (score 1):

Split your scraping up across multiple instances (say 5 per server) and have them talk to a central DB like Amazon RDS.

No need to kill the instances after you have finished scraping if your doing this every 120 seconds.